# python crash course 13-4 adding a new row of sprites lags pygame and new row does not move

Tags: python, pygame

I am currently doing an exercise in pyton crash course
Modify your code in Exercise 13-3 so when a row of raindrops
disappears off the bottom of the screen, a new row appears at the top of
the screen and begins to fall.
I have managed to make a new row of raindrops appear when the bottom row touches the bottom of the screen. Hwoever, upon doing so pygame starts to lag significantly, and after creating a new row of raindrops at the top of the screen the new row stays stationary while the original set of raindrops continues moving down (with significant lag). I have done some debugging and it appears that a large amount of new rows are being created once the first row touches the bottom, but I do not know why. Would appreciate any help kind sirs, thank yoU!

stars_game.py

```
import sys
import pygame
from settings import Settings
from star import Star
from random import randint

class StarGame:

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
            (0,0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
        self.settings.screen_width = self.screen.get_rect().width 
        self.settings.screen_height = self.screen.get_rect().height
        pygame.display.set_caption("Star Game")

        self.stars = pygame.sprite.Group()

        self._create_fleet()



    def run_game(self):
        while True:
            self._check_events()
            self._update_stars()
            self._update_screen()

            
    def _create_fleet(self):
        star = Star(self)
        star_width, star_height = star.rect.size
        available_space_x = self.settings.screen_width - (2 * star_width) 
        number_stars_x = available_space_x // (2 * star_width)

        available_space_y = (self.settings.screen_height - 2 * star_height)
        number_rows = available_space_y // (2 * star_height)
        for row_number in range(number_rows):
            for star_number in range(number_stars_x):
                    self._create_star(star_number, row_number)
            
    def _create_row(self):
        star = Star(self)
        star_width, star_height = star.rect.size
        available_space_x = self.settings.screen_width - (2 * star_width) 
        number_stars_x = available_space_x // (2 * star_width)

        available_space_y = (self.settings.screen_height - 2 * star_height)
        number_rows = available_space_y // (2 * star_height)
        for star_number in range(number_stars_x):
            self._create_star(star_number, 0)

    def _create_star(self, star_number, row_number):
        star = Star(self)
        star_width, star_height = star.rect.size
        star.x = star_width + 2 * star_width * star_number
        star.rect.x = star.x
        star.y = star.rect.height + 2 * star.rect.height * row_number
        star.rect.y = star.y
        self.stars.add(star)

    def _update_stars(self):
        """Update the positions of all stars in the fleet."""
        self._check_fleet_edges()
        self.stars.update()

    def _check_events(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                    sys.exit()

    def _update_screen(self):
        self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
        self.stars.draw(self.screen)
        pygame.display.flip()

    def _check_fleet_edges(self):
        flag = False
        for star in self.stars.sprites():
            if star.check_edges():
                star.remove()
                flag = True
        if flag:
            self._create_row()
            print("NEW")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sg = StarGame()
    sg.run_game()
```

settings.py

```
class Settings:
    """A class to store all settings for Alien Invasion."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialise the game's settings."""
        #Screen settings
        self.screen_width = 1200
        self.screen_height = 800
        self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)

        self.star_speed = 1.0
```

star.py

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite 

class Star(Sprite):

    def __init__(self, sg_game):
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = sg_game.screen
        self.settings = sg_game.settings

        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/alien.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = self.rect.width
        self.rect.y = self.rect.height
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)
        self.y = float(self.rect.y)

    def update(self):
        self.y += self.settings.star_speed
        self.rect.topleft = round(self.x), round(self.y)

    def check_edges(self):
        screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
        if self.rect.y >= screen_rect.bottom:
            return True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the stars are at the bottom of the screen, they need to be removed from the `stars` [`Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group). You have to pass the *Group* from which the *stars* are to be removed to the [`remove`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite.remove) method. Alternatively you can remove a stars from all groups with [`kill`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite.kill):

```py
class StarGame:
    # [...]

    def _check_fleet_edges(self):
        flag = False
        for star in self.stars.sprites():
            if star.check_edges():
                
                star.remove(self.stars)          # <---
                # alternatively you can do
                # star.kill()     
           
                flag = True
        if flag:
            self._create_row()
            print("NEW")
```

---

[`pygame.image.load`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load) is a very time consuming operation. The image file must be read and decoded. Load the image once during the initialization and pass the loaded [`Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object to the constructor of `Star`:

```py
class Star(Sprite):

    def __init__(self, sg_game, image):
        # [...]

        self.image = image
        
        # [...]
```

```py
class StarGame:
    def __init__(self):
        # [...]

        self.star_surf = pygame.image.load('images/alien.bmp')

    # [...]

    def _create_fleet(self):
        star = Star(self, self.star_surf) 
        # [...]

    def _create_row(self):
        star = Star(self, self.star_surf)
        # [...]

    def _create_star(self, star_number, row_number):
        star = Star(self, self.star_surf)
        # [...]
```

Comment: Hi sir, thank you for the help and the information. Doesnt .remove work in the way such as list/group.remove(specific_item_to_be_removed)? IN this case in star.remove(self.stars) isnt star a specific sprite and "Self.stars" the group of sprites? Cheers!

Comment: @BobTan `self.stars` is the group the starts will be added to with `self.stars.add(star)`. Please follow the links in the answer. Read the documentation of **[`remove()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite.remove)** and **[`kill()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite.kill)**

Comment: Ohh i see. Thank you!